# Finding Ads on a web page

Tags: javascript, python, html, ads, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing an application that's trying to determine if there are ads on a page. This is currently using brower-driving through selenium webdriver using python.

I figured that a good amount of ads exist inside iframes, and I've made a loop to look inside each frame

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://cnn.com")

all_iframes = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")

for iframe in all_iframes:
   browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)
   print(browser.page_source)
   browser.switch_to_default_content()

browser.quit()
```

I'm wondering if there is any consistently found  tags or tag parameters that I can use across multiple pages to determine if there are ads located on a page (both in and outside of iframes on a page). Would I have to look for instances of stuff like doubleclick or adtech or adblade inside each frame?

Or would I have to generate different rules for checking on a per-page basis?

Anyone in the know about how ads are displayed on pages? Thanks.

Comment: Iframe content from a different domain are not accessible from the parent page due to the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Yeah. It's reading the content of about 12 of them, but viewing source is showing up 28 on this example I just ran. 

I'm wondering if there's just a common set of parameters in frames or something that lets you know if it's an ad or not

Comment: I think the SRC would. Here's a list of common ad servers: http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=hosts

Comment: So you think maybe just seeking out instances of ad-server names is a viable way to determine of a page has ads on it?

What about banner ads that are just images?

Comment: The banner ads have to be served up from somewhere.

Comment: Tru-fax. I'm going to see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can search by the ad servers.

http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/serverlist.php?hostformat=adblockplus

It would be helpful to look at other projects and see how they handle doing the same task:

http://adblockplus.org/en/source