# finding advertisements on a page with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am doing a script to detect if there is an adversment present in a page with javascript.Most of the advertisements are coming  in an i frame. So I have done some code like

```
window = 'Url_of_the_website_to_be_checked';
if(window != window.top) 
{
console.log('adv detected');
} else {
console.log('adv not found');
}
```

But when i run the code i didnt get the expexcted output even if the page has advertisements.

How can this be done with js actually.Is there any other way to do this ??..

Any help would be really helpful and appreciated..Thanx

Comment: What's the value of `window.top`? Perhaps you want to be iterating over `window.top.frames` to check?

Comment: @gvee i have checked window.top.check ..but still the result is same..could you give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer provides a list of known advertiser domain names, which may be useful

[Finding Ads on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423219/finding-ads-on-a-web-page)

To detect advertisements on a page, I would check for iframes on the page and then check to see if the iframe's src domain is in a list of known advertisers. You could just check to see if it matches the current websites domain but this would identify external scripts/widgets like Facebook like buttons as advertisements as they use embedded iframes too.

You can use the below code to get the src

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var frame = frames[0];
var srcString = frame.src
```

You could then extract the domain name from this src string and compare to your list of advertisers, which could simply be an array or stored within a database.

This code should help get all iframes on the website using jQuery and get the domain for each

```
$('iframe').each(function(index, frm) {
  if (undefined != frm.src && frm.src != '') {
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = frm.src;
    console.log(parser.hostname);
  }
});
```

You can do it without jQuery if needed

Comment: how could i check multiple websites if it has a frame ?

Comment: If you would like to check an external website for advertisements you would probably best using a headless browser such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). This could load up the site and load all of the pages scripts. Then you can search against the websites DOM. To check multiple you could keep the list of sites to test in a database or an array and just iterate over it.

Comment: on the first link you gave me was python and the second link was not related to the subject

Comment: Hi, The first link's accepted answer provides links that would be good research for what your trying to acheive. It provides a list of known advertisers which would be handy to reference against. The second link shows how to access the window object of an iframe. Comparing `window != window.top` when window is a string will not work. [MDN Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window)

Comment: yes but see here in the second example you gave me ..it is creating an element iframe..i dont want to create one i just want to check if the loaded page has an iframe ?

Comment: waitingfor ur updated answer and please provide some code ..it would be helful.:)

Comment: I have updated the answer, some of the comments are now not relevant (refer to removed links etc) so I'm going to remove them.

Comment: see my question is how can i check if a website has an iframe.see you havnt mentioned even a website name to check it ..do i wanna add ..`window.location = 'thewebsiteurl'; before the frames variable` i havnt seen mentioning the website name..P:S the website which i want to check the advertisement is not my website its other ones

Comment: In order to read the contents of a website you need to read the websites DOM (Document Object Model). To do this programatically you would need to make a request to the website to get the information. To do this you could use Curl `curl --request GET 'www.bbc.co.uk'` which would return the source code for the page BUT... most advertisements are loaded by javascript after the page has loaded, Curl wont run the javascript code so advertisements would not load. Which is why I've provided a link for you to read up on PhantomJS, This would allow you to read the DOM of the fully rendered page

Comment: so you mean this can be done with phantom js only.??

Comment: Not only PhantomJs, Have a search for javascript headless browsers. These run on NodeJs. A headless browser will allow you to fully load the page you wish to work with, then you can search the DOM for what you need.

Comment: thanx for the help and finally a question ..can this action be done with ajax ??

Comment: Yes, You could make an ajax request to a NodeJs backend which would then load up the required site and search it for advertisements and return the results, here is an example of how PhantomJs could be used for a similar project. [Scraping AdSense Ads with PhantomJs](http://www.garysieling.com/blog/scraping-adsense-ads-with-phantomjs)

Comment: thanx for ur help so far..Have you seen the extension adblock ..it searches for advertisements without a request on the page..hows it done like that ..any idea ?

Comment: A browser extension runs within the browser, so it has access to the document / window object directly.