# Is there any way to know the frequency at which ads are uploaded to a webpage with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, upload, rate, ads

I am doing some statistic with the rate at which people use to upload ads to a selling-website, questions to a forum, videos to YouTube, etc. (in particular I am mostly interested about the data related with ads). The thing is that I want to measure this rate myself (without any data base reported by someone else).

I have a script (in `python` also using `selenium`) that performs the basic things to open url's and navigate.

1. So, is there any way to know the time instance at which a given advertisement, for example, has been uploaded or how many of them in a certain time window? Is it registered in the webpage some information related with?
2. In the answer is "Yes", how can I access to that data from `selenium`?

I know it is kind of a general question since I am not being specific about a webpage in particular, so I apologize :)
I'd be glad if someone could help with that, thanks in advance. Any answer or comment would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can get that information, unless the site specifically provides it.  You can tell how often a page _displays new ads_, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Maybe helpful or related [Finding Ads on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423219/finding-ads-on-a-web-page)